# Unable to copy to Amazon S3 using Full Administrator access and Full S3 access

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, migration, amazon-iam, wp-cli

I had a perfectly working instance of a WP-CLI wordpress plugin to upload files to S3 using the AmazonS3FullAccess policy. I migrated servers, and the copy started failing. "Failed to copy or write".

I even included the **Full Administrator** access to the IAM policy just to see what's going on when there are no restrictions, and the copy is still failing. Any idea what might be wrong?

Things I have tried: ensure time (via NTPD synchronization) on the new server is correct. Cross check the environment: php version, etc. The application files are exactly the same. I also used the host files method to check the previous server and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating new access keys. For some reason, it seems that migrating a server will make the old access keys stop working? Ah, well.

P.S. I also downgraded the policies right back, to only what the application needs.